# Searching through string of characters

Tags: c, string

i have problem making program in which u could "draw" map using "S" as start "#" as route and "E" as end, and program would tell you the way. Problem is that when i draw the map I'm not able to search throught characters in strings.
  here is sample of my wrong code that never finds the "S":

```
 char array[5][10];

 for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
     gets(array[i]);
 }

for(i=0;i<=5;i++){

    for(j=0;j<=10;j++){

       if(array[i][j]=="S"){
            printf("something");
       }
       else printf("something");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and I suspect the problems in this code will be reported to you by the compiler itself.

Comment: Tag the programming language you're using. Is this language-agnostic?

Answer (score 4):

Your character comparison is incorrect

```
if(array[i][j]=="S"){
```

should become

```
if(array[i][j]=='S'){
```

Double quotes `""` enclose a string literal, not a character.

Comment: See @Ivaylo Strandjev's response, too.

Answer (score 2):

Valid indexes in an array of size `N` in c++ are 0 upto **N-1**. In all your cycles you access elements 0 up to **N**. You access an out of bounds element and thus invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: but in 
         for(i=0;i<5;i++){
   gets(cis[i]);
    }
it let me write just 4 lines.

Comment: @user3007863 the cycle is executed 5 times, but the first gets read the newline character leftover from the input before the cycle.

Comment: You can add a gets to read one line before the cycle and ignore the value read from this gets.